# Off Screen Scrolling - Override Default Behavior

Tags: android, flutter, accessibility

On any smartphone, when scrolling starts from outside the top of the screen and continues all the way down, the system opens the device's action menu, providing access to shortcuts such as WiFi, Bluetooth, and brightness. Specifically on Android, is it possible to override this behavior and perform a different action within an app?

In other words, can scrolling be detected when it originates from off the screen, regardless of its starting point?

I am aware that scrolling within the screen borders can be detected, but I haven't been able to find a way to detect scrolling when it begins from outside the screen borders, such as in the case of the action menu.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.